# You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

Tags: powershell

We have a Powers-hell script running on our SP 2007 environment and what it does is collecting SharePoint list attachment and move it folder path. However since last month I am receiving attached error message. Nothing has been change and I am not sure why the error is coming up.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
enter code here
```

```
#USAGE:  .\CopyImagesFromGreensListDateParams.ps1 -startDate "1 July 2016" -finishDate "31 July 2016"

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0 , Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c")

$parsedStartDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-14)
$parsedStartDate = [microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility]::CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime($parsedStartDate)

$parsedFinishedDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
$parsedFinishedDate = [microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility]::CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime($parsedFinishedDate)
#---- Create Folder ----

$folderStartDate = get-date $parsedStartDate -Format 'yyyyMMdd'
$folderEndDate = get-date $parsedFinishedDate -Format 'yyyyMMdd'

$targetFolderLocation = $folderStartDate  + '-' + $folderEndDate

#---- End of Create Folder ----

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0 , Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c")

$outputPath = ("E:\Scripts\Greens\Output\"+$targetFolderLocation+"\")

$webUrl = "Site URL"    
$library = "Greens Form"   


$s = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($webUrl)    
$w = $s.OpenWeb()

$l = $w.Lists[$library]    
$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery

$camlQuery = "<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Created'/><Value Type='DateTime'>" + $parsedStartDate + "</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='Created'/><Value Type='DateTime'>" + $parsedFinishedDate + "</Value></Leq></And></Where>";

Write-Host $camlQuery

$spQuery.Query = $camlQuery
$sourceItems = $l.GetItems($spQuery)

Write-Host "Item Count: " $sourceItems.Count

if($sourceItems.Count -gt 0) 
{
    foreach ($listItem in $sourceItems)
    {
        Write-Host "" 
        Write-Host "ID: " $listItem.ID 
        #$destinationfolder = $outputPath + "\" + $listItem.ID
        $destinationfolder = $outputPath

        $focusSRNumber = $listItem['Case ID and Action ID']
        Write-Host "Case ID and Action ID: " $focusSRNumber

        $fullCompanyName =$listItem['Company Name']
        $companyName = $listItem['Company Name'].Substring(0,3).ToUpper()
        Write-Host "Company Name " $fullCompanyName

        $count = 0
        #$targetFileName = 'SR'+$focusSRNumber+$companyName+'00'+$count
        #Write-Host $targetFileName

        if (!(Test-Path -path $outputPath))        
        {            
            $dest = New-Item $outputPath -type directory          
        }

        # 'SR' + [Case ID and Action ID] + [First 3 chars of Company name] + [Sequence number ie. 001, 002 ]
        # SR789654SUN002

        $isPhotoProcessed = $listItem["Photo Processed"]
        if($isPhotoProcessed -ne "Yes")
        {
            foreach ($attachment in $listItem.Attachments)    
            {      
                $count++

                $file = $w.GetFile($listItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix + $attachment)  
                $fullFileName = $file.Name

                $extn = [IO.Path]::GetExtension($fullFileName)
                if(($extn -eq ".jpg") -or ($extn -eq "jpeg"))
                {
                    $targetFileName = 'SR'+$focusSRNumber+$companyName+'00'+$count+$extn            

                    $bytes = $file.OpenBinary()                
                    $path = $destinationfolder + $targetFileName 
                    Write "Saving $path" 
                    $fs = new-object System.IO.FileStream($path, "OpenOrCreate") 
                    $fs.Write($bytes, 0 , $bytes.Length)    
                    $fs.Close()  

                    # seems to be firing the magick resizer before the flush/close on the file stream; using sleep to wait for it to complete
                    Start-Sleep -s 3

                    Write-Host "Resizing: "$path

                    #magick convert "$path" -define jpeg:extent=512kb "$path"

                    $argument = "convert " + $path + " -define jpeg:extent=512kb " + $path
                    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16\magick.exe" -ArgumentList $argument
                }
            }

            $listItem["Photo Processed"] = "Yes"
            $listItem.Update()


        }
    }

}

# PHOTOS DOWNLOAD
$library = "Photo or Outlier Form"  

$l = $w.Lists[$library]    
$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery

$camlQuery = "<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name='Created'/><Value Type='DateTime'>" + $parsedStartDate + "</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name='Created'/><Value Type='DateTime'>" + $parsedFinishedDate + "</Value></Leq></And></Where>";

Write-Host $camlQuery

$spQuery.Query = $camlQuery
$sourceItems = $l.GetItems($spQuery)

Write-Host "Item Count: " $sourceItems.Count
if($sourceItems.Count -gt 0) 
{
    foreach ($listItem in $sourceItems)
    {
        Write-Host "" 
        Write-Host "ID: " $listItem.ID 
        #$destinationfolder = $outputPath + "\" + $listItem.ID
        $destinationfolder = $outputPath

        $focusSRNumber = $listItem['Case ID and Action ID']
        Write-Host "Case ID and Action ID: " $focusSRNumber

        $companyName = 'PFM'
        Write-Host "Company Name " $companyName

        $count = 0
        #$targetFileName = 'SR'+$focusSRNumber+$companyName+'00'+$count
        #Write-Host $targetFileName

        if (!(Test-Path -path $outputPath))        
        {            
            $dest = New-Item $outputPath -type directory          
        }

        # 'SR' + [Case ID and Action ID] + [First 3 chars of Company name] + [Sequence number ie. 001, 002 ]
        # SR789654SUN002

        $isPhotoProcessed = $listItem["Photo Processed"]
        if($isPhotoProcessed -ne "Yes")
        {
            foreach ($attachment in $listItem.Attachments)    
            {      
                $count++

                $file = $w.GetFile($listItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix + $attachment)  
                $fullFileName = $file.Name

                $extn = [IO.Path]::GetExtension($fullFileName)

                if(($extn -eq ".jpg") -or ($extn -eq "jpeg"))
                {
                    $targetFileName = 'SR'+$focusSRNumber+$companyName+'00'+$count+$extn            

                    $bytes = $file.OpenBinary()                
                    $path = $destinationfolder + $targetFileName 
                    Write "Saving $path" 
                    $fs = new-object System.IO.FileStream($path, "OpenOrCreate") 
                    $fs.Write($bytes, 0 , $bytes.Length)    
                    $fs.Close()  

                    # seems to be firing the magick resizer before the flush/close on the file stream; using sleep to wait for it to complete
                    Start-Sleep -s 3

                    Write-Host "Resizing: "$path

                    #magick convert "$path" -define jpeg:extent=512kb "$path"

                    $argument = "convert " + $path + " -define jpeg:extent=512kb " + $path
                    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.3-Q16\magick.exe" -ArgumentList $argument
                }
            }

            $listItem["Photo Processed"] = "Yes"
            $listItem.Update()


        }
    }
}


Regards 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z29CH.png
```

Comment: It would help to see your script to be able to troubleshoot.

Comment: what would be the best way to send the code?

Comment: You can either post it right here in your question using [this guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), or use a source tracking site like GitHub and put a link in your question.